# Prove that if K(kernel matrix) is a positive semi-definite matrix, then k is a dot product: $\exists \phi$ such that $k(x,y) = \phi(x).\phi(y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

If a kernel matrix is positive semi-definite, how can I prove there exists a $\phi$ s.t $k(x,y) = \phi(x).\phi(y)$

My method:
Every real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized, so we can write:
$$
K = PDP^T = \begin{bmatrix}
  \vert & \dots  &\vert \\
  p_1   & \dots & p_m   \\
  \vert & \dots &\vert
 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   d_{1} & & \\
   & \ddots & \\
   & & d_{m}
  \end{bmatrix} 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \text{---} & p_1^T & \text{---} \\
 \dots & \dots & \dots \\
 \text{---} & p_m^T & \text{---}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \vert & \dots  &\vert \\
  d_1p_1   & \dots & d_mp_m   \\
  \vert & \dots &\vert
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \text{---} & p_1^T & \text{---} \\
 \dots & \dots & \dots \\
 \text{---} & p_m^T & \text{---}
\end{bmatrix} = d_1 p_1p_1^T + \dots + d_m p_m p_m^T = M
$$

$$
M_{ij} = d_1 p_i^{(1)}p_j^{(1)} + \dots + d_m p_i^{(m)} p_j^{(m)} = \phi(x_i).\phi(x_j)
$$
$$
\phi(x_i) = (\sqrt{d_1}p^{(1)}_i, \sqrt{d_2}p_i^{(2)}, \dots, \sqrt{d_m}p_i^{(m)})
$$
$$
\phi(x_j) = (\sqrt{d_1}p^{(1)}_j, \sqrt{d_2}p_j^{(2)}, \dots, \sqrt{d_m}p_j^{(m)})
$$
What bothers me is that I haven't used the positive-semi definiteness property of the kernel matrix. Is there a mistake in my proof?

Comment: But why would that be necessary? Should every $\phi$ map to R?

Comment: Why would there be an issue, if $\phi$ mapped to $\mathbf{C}$

Comment: Each element of the (Mercel) kernel  matrix must be in $R^+$. If for some $d_i<0$ then $\phi(x_i)\cdot \pi(x_j)$ could be negative. The positive definiteness property with eigenvalues  $d_n≥0$ are what ensures $\phi \cdot \phi ≥0$

Comment: Where does the condition that every element of the kernel matrix must be in $R^+$ come from?

Comment: You had used that the matrix was positive semi-definite definite: $d_j\ge 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first start by assuming that the matrix $K(i,j)$ is positive definite. Then the form
$$\langle z,w\rangle =\sum_{i,j=1}^mK(i,j)z_i\bar{w}_j>0,\ z,w\in \mathbb{C}^m$$ defines an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^m.$
Let $e_1,_2,\ldots, e_m$ denote the standard basis in $\mathbb{C}^m.$ Let $u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_m$ denote the orthonormal basis with respect to this inner product. Thus
$$e_i=\sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik}u_k$$ for some coefficients $a_{ik}.$ Moreover by orthonormality we get
$$K(i,j)=\langle e_i,e_j\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}\bar{a}_{jk}=\varphi_i\bar\varphi_j$$
where $\varphi_l=(a_{l1},a_{l2},\ldots, a_{lm}).$

If the matrix is positive semidefinite there are two options. Either considering the quotient space $\mathbb{C}^m/\ker K$ or considering $K^{(n)}=K+{1\over n}I$ and then taking the accumulation point of $\{\varphi^{(n)}_{i}\}_{i=1}^m,$ the elements obtained for $K^{(n)}.$ The latter is possible as
by construction
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^m|a^{(n)}_{ij}|^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^m|K^{(n)}(i,j)|^2$$
so the elements $a_{ij}^{(n)}$ form a bounded set in $\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}.$

Comment: While your proof is fascinating, I still fail to see a mistake in my proof. I would appreciate it if you could point out where my mistake is.

Comment: I do not claim your proof is incorrect. I gave another proof to avoid applying diagonalization.

Comment: Then can you help me figure out why I didn't need the definiteness property of the kernel matrix?

Comment: You did use positive definitness . This is equivalent to $d_k\ge 0$ for all $k.$ There are square roots of $d_k$s in your solution.

Comment: But I said it to Han as well. Why does it matter if $\phi$ maps my data to a complex vector space?

Comment: There are two cases: symmetric real matrices or complex self-adjoint matrices. Both are diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. You are considering the first case. So no complex values are needed, so can restrict to real valued quantities.